# resolvconf Error when running dhclient in recovery mode

Tags: networking, dns, resolvconf

when I go to recovery mode and I want to activate networking, I usually type:

```
dhclient eth0
```

After this, I can for example ping to www.google.com.

However, I get the following error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
resolvconf: Error: /run/resolvconf/interface either does not exist or is not a directory
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

And try again.